# Visual Studio 2017 Live Visual Tree doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio, visual-tree

I can't enable **Live Visual Tree** in **Visual Studio 2017** for UWP app (C#).  This tool was working on VS2015, but never worked for me in VS2017. It works with no problems for my WPF projects.

I'm getting the following error message in `Live Visual Tree`:

> UI debugging requires the latest version of the SDK and the Universal
>   Windows App Development Tools. Ensure that these tools are installed
>   to enable UI Debugging.

What I tried:

1. Make sure that `Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML` is Checked in `Options/Debugging`.
2. Reinstalled `Windows 10 SDK (10.0.15063.0) for UWP: C#, VB, JS`

I can't find any information about the issue (relevant to **VS 2017**, although found some info about VS2015) in web or in Stack Overflow. Please help.

Comment: Thank you! Wrote to support. I will share the solution here if they'll help

Comment: Actually, this button in VS simple post the problem on Microsoft Community Forum. This is not a bad idea, but it doesn't really different from posting here (except that here you get answers much faster)

Comment: So, I reported a problem on Microsoft Community over 2 weeks now, but get 0 answers so far. The problem persists.

Comment: BTW, I noticed that Live Visual Tree works for WPF apps, but not for UWP.

Answer (score 1):

After contacting Microsoft, they told me check if I have the following file:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\bin\x86\XamlDiagnostics\XamlDiagnostics.dll

I didn't even have a folder `XamlDiagnostics`.

Then I was asked to **(re)install Windows 10 SDK**. I downloaded the latest SDK from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and after I installed it, the problem gone.

Great thanks to Evgeny Tvorun [MSFT] who helped me with the issue.

The Visual Tree tool is really great and I feel lost all that time I was without it.